# SVG Polygon - % Scaling

Tags: html, svg, height, width, polygon

Is it possible to set the points of a SVG polygon to %-values, of the surrounding SVG? This is a regular SVG Polygon:

```
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
<polygon points="10,10 10,100 100,100" style="fill:#000">
</svg>
```

Is it possible to to something like this (this example does not work):

```
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
<polygon points="10%,10% 10%,100% 100%,100%" style="fill:#000">
</svg>
```

With this one could, for example, adjust the size of a polygon without having to adjust every single point. One could just simply adjust the height/width of the surrounding SVG.

Comment: Replace ems by % in the linked answer

Comment: Sorry, I tried but it didn't really work.. Is it advanced? Why can't I just use the "%" like in my example?

Comment: Because the SVG specification says only numbers without units are allowed. If you edit the question to explain why it didn't work it can be reopened.